# Converting latex file (.tex) to html file

Tags: html, latex

I need to make a .tex file an html page.
I looked around and i didn't find any good solution to my problem, or, for example tex4ht (or htlatex), i absolutly don't know how to use it.

I just installed Miktex 2.9 using the basic installer from their [site](https://miktex.org/download), nothing more.
Also tried the command `htlatex test` (test.tex is my test file), and it happend to do only a small part of the job.

Any routine to properly make some html files out of .tex files ?

Answer (score 0):

it will work maybe using,

http://jwork.org/rtextdoc/

Here the doc about that part :

http://jwork.org/wiki/RTextDoc:Latex

Comment: The demo version does not detect any latex related, i tried to put it in diferent places such as Miktex root directory, but still...

Comment: you can try to use kile : http://kile.sourceforge.net/ which have a module laTex to web

Comment: Learning how kile works until now, i think it's a good LaTex editor, and it can preview html files, but not convert to html.... well it can export to html, but what you get is kinda funny ^^ : http://imgur.com/a/DiH6L Actually it's a html page that contains span tag to display latex's code

Comment: hope you'll find a better way, (I found this : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2html but never use, don't know....) Sorry...I don't think there is an "easy way"....

Comment: I managed to use it on Ubuntu VM with tex4ht and htlatex, and it worked pretty good except some graphics did not appear for some reason, but that's not very hard to fix... However, I have a problem to display it as an utf 8 encoded document now, (the html file from htlatex is unix encoded, and it cause many probmems...). I think i'll ask for this in an other place... Thank you anyway